# Select anchors without href

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I'd like to change the css style of all the anchors without `href` attribute.

I can use selector to select anchors that start with something using `$('a[href^="some_link"]')` . But I want it to be vice versa. How can I select anchors without href using jquery?

Also, can I achieve this using a css selector?

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll want this selector (jQuery/CSS compatible):

```
a:not([href])
```

If you need IE support (because of that `:not()`), use it as a jQuery selector. Otherwise, you can use it for a CSS rule.

Comment: it's weird that `a[href]` also select the elements without a `href`

Answer (score 3):

Use `$("a").filter(function() { return !this.attributes['href']; })`.

It's a little longer, but browsers can optimise the selection of the anchors, and do the filtering faster than Sizzle (or querySelectorAll) can run.

http://jsfiddle.net/9PWQB/